# cURL PHP script work everywhere except on iPhoneq

Tags: php, curl

I've been struggling since 1 month trying to find how every browser, every mobile phone except iPhone, can accept my cURL URL request but not on iPhone?

I mean, when I go to URL to call the cURL (via the URL which is a PHP file, it always give me an empty query).

I tried every possible way, user-agent, header, SSL, with cURL option and nothing working.

Every browser working and also every Samsung phone, why does iPhone ignore it?

I also tried it with Safari that I've downloaded for Windows, and work well.

Anybody already had these issues?

I just don't know what to do, there nothing to help me find the problem, no tools... :(

Here is the cURL call (this is a function but you got it how i call it):

```
  private function __request($url, $post = false, array $headers = NULL, $decode_json = true){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    if($post){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, is_array($post) ? http_build_query($post) : $post);
    }
    if($headers){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if($decode_json){
        return json_decode($data);
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't get how you call it, and that likely is the issue because the PHP isn't on the phone. Can you please explain/show how you call it?

Comment: What you mean ?